# UI reasoning in Graphics Design: Why does escape not cancel selection in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, selections

I am completely new to Graphic Design and I am using Gimp.

As you can imagine, the first few steps are a hate-love relationship kinda thing.

I found that the selection tool is at the core of the things I am currently fiddling around with. Sadly, every time I selected something, the next step would not come easily because the selection just won't go away. I googled a bit and I stumbled across this really really great [Gimp Unstuck FAQ](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-getting-unstuck.html). Turns out, (on Windows) you have to press `Shift+Ctrl+A` to cancel selection.

Is there any historical reason as to why the `Esc` key is not used for this, like it is in most other apps and games?

Comment: Yeah, I already have a "selection mask" in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On selecting an area we can cancel the selection using the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key until this selection was converted into a selection mask.

[image]

In above example we already had a rectangular selection where we are about to add another elliptical selection. At this time we can cancel the elliptical selection using <kbd>ESC</kbd>, as expected.

The reason why Gimp uses another key combination (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) is to avoid deletion of the whole selection using <kbd>ESC</kbd> while we are adding another selection to our pre-existing mask.

In case we are not happy with the default key combinations we can define our own keyboard shortcuts with *Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts*:

[image]